# Card flip transitions not working properly in IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, css-transitions, ng-animate

I have made an example of a card flip in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n0m8d4zg/4/) for AngularJS.

It works perfectly in Chrome.
It works OK in Firefox.
It sort of works in IE, but not properly.

As soon as I remove the perspective css rule it works perfectly (with no perspective).  If I add the -webkit- and -ie- rules it still doesn't work. IS THIS A BUG I IE.

I have used the ng-enter and ng-leave to make the transitions etc. Check JSFiddle for full code.

```
.serviceRoll{
    margin:32px;
    position: relative;
    height:150px;
    width:215px;
    perspective:800px;
}
.rollInner {
    background-color:lightgrey;
    padding-top:50px;
    height:100px;
    width:215px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:2em;
    border-radius: 16px;
}
.roll {
    position: absolute;
}
.roll.ng-enter {
    -webkit-transition:0.25s ease all;
    transition:0.25s ease all;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    z-index: 1;
}
.roll.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s;
    transition-delay: 0.25s;
}
.roll.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transition:0.25s ease all;
    transition:0.25s ease all;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    z-index: -1;
}
.roll.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(90deg);
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where you have -webkit- also add a css rule for -ms- as well. You have added these rules in for webkit browsers but not for non-webkit browsers. Take a few of your css rules as an example. Something like this -

```
.roll.ng-enter {
    -webkit-transition:0.25s ease all;
    -ms-transition:0.25s ease all;
    transition:0.25s ease all;
    -ms-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    z-index: 1;
}
.roll.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.25s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 0.25s;
    transition-delay: 0.25s;
}
.roll.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transition:0.25s ease all;
    -ms-transition:0.25s ease all;
    transition:0.25s ease all;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

You get the idea :)
Hope this helps!

Comment: I have tried that already. With ms rules http://jsfiddle.net/n0m8d4zg/5/. In IE the transition goes half way then goes blank till the next $interval.

Comment: A few things this could be - 
Are you using the latest version of IE?
If you do not have a proper doctype declaration as the very first line in a document, IE will enter compatibility mode and most features will not work as expected. Ensure that you have a valid doctype (<!DOCTYPE html> will be fine) and add <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> to your document <head>.

Comment: I have all these in my main project and would probably be included in the JSFiddle project, but still no luck. I think its an IE bug - typically.